# How do i build a tracking other gps user feature using google maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, gps

I know the question is a little bit subjective, but bear with me, i will explain my current confusion

My goal is to build something similar like uber feature where i can track driver who has accepted my request, it will be on IOS only for now

1) There will be many drivers on the map

2) a consumer decided to go from **current location** to **targeted location**

3) one of the drivers accept it and now the consumer can track the driver

As to my research, I need to Google map sdk for IOS, and i need to know about google map web service api and as well as google distance matrix api.

Any advice on how to approach this problem? and do i need a serverside for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#Introduction), it will give you a service that provides travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations. The information returned is based on the recommended route between start and end points, as calculated by the Google Maps API.

**The required parameters are:**

- `origin` - it serves as the location/starting point for calculating distance and time.

> `origins=Bobcaygeon+ON|41.43206,-81.38992`

- `destination` - it serves as the finished point for calculating distance and time.

> `destinations=Darling+Harbour+NSW+Australia|24+Sussex+Drive+Ottawa+ON|Capitola+CA`

**The following example uses latitude/longitude coordinates to specify the destination coordinates:**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626%7C40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

**Distance Matrix API also have optional parameters like:**

- `mode` (defaults to driving) — Specifies the mode of transport to use when calculating distance. Valid values and other request details are specified in the [Travel Modes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters) section.
- `avoid` — Introduces restrictions to the route. Valid values are specified in the Restrictions section of this document. Only one restriction can be specified.
- `arrival_time` — Specifies the desired time of arrival for transit requests, in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. You can specify either departure_time or arrival_time, but not both. Note that arrival_time must be specified as an integer.
- `departure_time` — The desired time of departure. You can specify the time as an integer in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. Alternatively, you can specify a value of now, which sets the departure time to the current time (correct to the nearest second).

**For using GPS in Google Maps for IOS, you can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980527/follow-user-location-on-google-maps?rq=1).**